# Google Map v2: "Android" extracting waypoint from json after passing string array

Tags: android, json, google-maps

The code below takes 2 address point and show it on the map, however i wanted to edit it by adding "waypoint" on the application. My question is, how can i extract the waypoint information from the json like how start and end information extracted below.

```
    public class DirectionJsonParser {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "key";
    private DirectionJsonListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;

    public DirectionJsonParser(DirectionJsonListener listener, String origin, String destination) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();
        new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl());
    }

    private String createUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");
        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "utf-8");

        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng(
                    lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d
            ));
        }

        return decoded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `JSON` to `String`, you can use the **JSONStringer**. Implements `toString() and toString()`. Most application developers should use those methods directly and disregard this API.

```
JSONObject object = ...
 String json = object.toString();
```

Each stringer may be used to encode a single top level value. Instances of this class are not thread safe. Although this class is nonfinal, it was not designed for inheritance and should not be subclassed. In particular, self-use by overrideable methods is not specified.

Stringers only encode well-formed JSON strings. In particular:

- The stringer must have exactly one top-level array or object.
- Lexical scopes must be balanced: every call to [`array()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html#array()) must have a matching call to ['endArray()'](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html#endArray()) and every call to object() must have a matching call to endObject().
- Arrays may not contain keys (property names).
- Objects must alternate keys (property names) and values.
- Values are inserted with either literal value calls, or by nesting arrays or objects.

Calls that would result in a malformed JSON string will fail with a JSONException. Some implementations of the API support at most 20 levels of nesting. Attempts to create more than 20 levels of nesting may fail with a [JSONException](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html).